# Dismissing a view controller and opening another one once complete, giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I process some photos and once thats done, I call the following function to show the output UI. I need to ensure that the current capture view controller is dismissed and don't want it running in the background. The function I use is this:

```
-(void)openOutputUIWithImage:(UIImage*)displayImage{ //update UI with new viewcontroller with specified image to display
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    outputView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OutputView"];
    outputView.img = displayImage;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:outputView animated:YES completion:^{
            NSLog(@"output view opened!");
        }];
    }];
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <OutputViewController: 0x100858af0> on <CircleDetectionViewController: 0x100857c20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, I haven't had much experience working with multiple view controllers. It seems to hit my viewDidLoad method in my other view controller but just displays a blank screen. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
UIViewController* presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [presentingViewController presentViewController:outputView animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];
```

Referenced this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33058529/5071756

Answer (score 0):

Who is `self` in this code? Based on the error, `self` is your `CircleDetectionViewController`. That means what's happening here is that `dismissViewControllerAnimated` causes the calling VC to dismiss itself (so that it is not in the view hierarchy anymore, and then tries to present a view controller on top of itself even though it has just been dismissed.

2 possible fixes come to mind:

1. Present your `OutputViewController` on top of your `CircleDetectionViewController` without dismissing it first.
2. Handle the logic for dismissing/presenting outside of these presented view controllers, in whatever the parent view controller is.

Comment: Is there a way to dismiss a previous view controller from present one?

Answer (score 0):

First unnecessarily allocating `OutputViewController` and getting the `OutputViewController` again from the story board. So     `OutputViewController* outputView = [[OutputViewController alloc] init];`
 line of code is not required.

You are trying to open a `OutputViewController` inside the completion block of the `CircleDetectionViewController dismissViewController` method. You are trying to open a `OutputViewController` on top of the `CircleDetectionViewController`. But your dismissing the `CircleDetectionViewController` that is wrong.

Get the previous view controller of the `CircleDetectionViewController` and present the `OutputViewController` from that and dismiss the `CircleDetectionViewController`.

**Update 1:**

First present the outputView

```
[self.presentingViewController presentViewController:outputView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And dismiss the CircleDetectionView

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'll edit that, sorry I was testing with init, was never there before.

Comment: Is there a way to present the view controller from the previous view controller, such as `[PreviousViewController presentViewController:outputView animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Alternatively can i use an NSNotification to trigger a method in previous view controller to instantiate the new one?

Comment: I'm getting the same result of a blank screen, but that error has disappeared. I'm getting the following:
`This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.`

Comment: sorry, change the `self.presentedViewController` into `self.presentingViewController`

Comment: You are updating some ui on background thread thats the reason you are getting that warning message

Comment: Thanks I got it to work using a similar method you suggested, I'm posting my solution!